# Create android AVD without 3G connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-wifi

One of the functions in my app sends data over the internet.  Before attempting to send the data, I check whether a connection exists:

```
private boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo.State val1 = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();
    NetworkInfo.State val2 = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
    return NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED.equals(val1) || NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED.equals(val2);
}
```

This worked perfectly fine on emulator and a couple of real devices I tested on.  Then I received an error report from the client, which on investigation turned out to be a `NullPointerException` on `getState` line for `TYPE_MOBILE`.

Apparently, `connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)` returned `null` on the device that didn't have 3G (a WiFi-only tablet).  Although I did test on a Nexus 7 emulator, I didn't get this error.

Hence, what I'm interested in is creating an AVD that explicitly does not have 3G (i.e. an AVD for a WiFi-only device) so that I could investigate/test such scenarios.  I haven't found anything in the emulator options, but maybe I'm just looking in a wrong place. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple solution to this.  In the mean time, I adopted my code to look like this:

```
private boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info1 = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    NetworkInfo info2 = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo.State val1 = (info1 == null ? null : info1.getState());
    NetworkInfo.State val2 = (info2 == null ? null : info2.getState());
    return (info1 != null && NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED.equals(val1)) || (info2 != null && NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED.equals(val2));
}
```

This takes care of `null` values when an interface is not present.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change the hardware settings for an AVD to remove the modem. The option is labeled `hw.gsmModem`, but I believe it disables all "cell data" connectivity, not just GSM.

If you want to change hardware options without using the AVD Manager, edit the `config.ini` file found in the avd's folder. By default, the folder is located at:

- **Linux/Mac:**  ~/.android/avd/yourAvdName
- **Windows Vista/7/(8?):** C:\Users\.android\yourAvdName
- **Windows XP:** C:\Documents and Settings\.android\yourAvdName

Just add a line that says:

```
hw.gsmModem=no
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#hardwareopts) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) for more detail.

---

However, you may be able to test it by turning off 3G instead, by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> in the emulator. I don't know if that will simulate the null you're looking for, but it's worth a shot.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping) for more shortcuts.

Comment: I tried turning off 3G data - this simulates turning off 3G data in the phone - and connection info isn't null, instead its getState returns DISCONNECTED.  Clearly this is not what I am after.

Comment: I can't even find where to remove hw.gsmModem.  The latest version of the ADV manager doesn't give me those options. I suppose, I could hunt down the xml for the avd, but disabling all cell data isn't an option for me.  I guess I'll just add checks for nulls.

Comment: I haven't updated my AVD manager in a bit, but you don't need it to change the options either way. Edited with instructions.